# Поиск гласных с помощью регулярных выражений на Java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь написать выражение чтобы в слове считалось кол-во гласных букв,но если буква `е` стоит в конце или 2 гласные буквы идут подряд-такие не считать.Пока пытаюсь сделать первое условие,но не понимаю почему выражение вида 
`String regex="([(aioeuy)&&[^e]$])";`
не работает.Ищу вот так:

```
                String str="capaciotyye";
                Matcher r = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str);
                while(r.find()) {count++;}
                System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: А что за `&&` в регулярке? Если вы пытаесь условие прописать, то это не сработает. Добавьте пример данных

Comment: В дополнение к предыдущему комментатору могу сказать, что в регулярных выражениях всё является "И", кроме случая, когда вы явно указываете ИЛИ знаком модуля |.

Comment: @gil9red добавил пример строки,но по сути строка может быть любая,которая оканчивается на "е"

Comment: @hwak в данном случае он считает совпадения левой части и исключает(вычитает)условие в правой части.Без && у меня,по крайне мере, не получилось

Comment: В общем, `$` и любые другие шаблоны типа "non-consuming"  в символьных  классах являются обычными сиволами. Конец строки нельзя указать в символьном классе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно разделить код на две части:

- Фильтр слов по условию
- Подсчет букв

Пример:

```
for (String word : Arrays.asList("are", "one", "round", "hello", "world")) {
    // Ищем слова с двумя буквами подряд или те, что оканчиваются на e
    Matcher match = Pattern.compile("[aioeuy]{2}|e$").matcher(word);
    if (match.find()) {
        continue;
    }

    // Подсчет количества букв
    match = Pattern.compile("[aioeuy]").matcher(word);
    int count = 0;
    while(match.find()) {count++;}
    System.out.println(word + " -> " + count);
}
```

Результат:

```
hello -> 2
world -> 1
```

---

**UPD.** После уточнения вопроса:

```
for (String word : Arrays.asList("are", "one", "round", "hello", "world", "heelloe")) {
    String origWord = word;

    // Ищем слова с двумя буквами подряд или те, что оканчиваются на e
    Matcher match = Pattern.compile("([aioeuy])\\1|e$").matcher(word);
    if (match.find()) {
        word = match.replaceAll("");
    }

    // Подсчет количества букв
    match = Pattern.compile("[aioeuy]").matcher(word);
    int count = 0;
    while(match.find()) {count++;}
    System.out.println(origWord + " -> " + count);
}
```

Результат:

```
are -> 1
one -> 1
round -> 2
hello -> 2
world -> 1
heelloe -> 1
```

Comment: Мне кажется вы неправильно поняли,суть проблемы,или я плохо объяснил.Я имел ввиду под "если буква е стоит в конце или 2 гласные буквы идут подряд-такие не считать." не считать ИМЕННО буквы,а не слова в целом.Например в слове hello=2, а в heelloe-1

Comment: @Андрей Всё очень непонятно. Обновите вопрос, пожалуйста, добавьте примеры и приведите желаемый результат.

Comment: @Андрей, у `heelloe` ведь будет 0, т.к. игнорируется две пары подряд идущих букв: `ee` и `oe`

Comment: @gil9red подряд одинаковых букв

Comment: @Андрей, в вопросе такого условия не было. Пишите сразу всё включая данные и ожидаемый результат, уважайте чужое время :) Обновил ответ

Comment: @gil9red простите:(Спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: @Андрей, пожалуйста )